# Java - Rock Paper Scissors - Loops an additional time if wrong and counts the number of wins

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, if-statement

I had to make a rock paper scissor game that loops 5 times and additional if you input an invalid number. I haven't been able to get it to loop enough if wrong, whenever I put an incorrect variable, it does loop additional times, but way too many times, and I only need 5 correct times. It also wont count the amount of player and computer scores. No matter how many each opponent gets right, it only displays Player Wins: 1 and Computer Win: 1. Please help! Here's my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class bmahipat_C5Lab1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        int player = 0, computer = 0;
        int computerScore = 0, playerScore = 0;
        int loops = 0;

        int rock = 1;
        int paper = 2;
        int scissors = 3;

        for(int i=1; i<6;i++) {
            computer = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors");
            player = reader.nextInt();

            if (player > scissors) {
                System.out.println("Not a valid response");
                System.out.println("Enter 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors");
                player = reader.nextInt();
                i = -1;
            }

            if (player == computer) {
                System.out.println("Tie");
            } else if (player == rock ) {
                if(computer == paper){
                    System.out.println ("Player picked Rock, Computer picked Paper, Computer wins");
                    computerScore = +1;
                } else if(computer == scissors) {
                    System.out.println ("Player picked Rock, Computer picked Scissors, Player wins");
                    playerScore = +1;
                }    
            } else if (player == paper) {
                if(computer == rock){
                    System.out.println ("Player picked Paper, Computer picked Rock , Player wins");
                    playerScore = +1;
                } else if(computer == scissors) {
                    System.out.println ("Player picked Paper, Computer picked Scissors, Computer wins");
                    computerScore = +1;
                }   
            } else if (player == scissors) {
                if(computer == rock) {
                    System.out.println ("Player picked Scissors, Computer picked Rock , Computer wins");
                    computerScore = +1;
                } else if(computer == paper) {
                    System.out.println ("Player picked Scissors, Computer picked Paper, Player wins");
                    playerScore = +1;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Computer Wins " + computerScore);
        System.out.println("Player Wins " + playerScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code `= +1` is the same as `= 1` most likely you meant `+= 1`

Comment: Instead of looking a fixed number of times, perhaps you should look until a fixed number of games have been played?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between

```
computerScore =+ 1; // This is computerScore = (+1) So it will be always 1
```

and

```
computerScore += 1; // this is equals to computerScore=computerScore+1;
```

and the same logic for

```
  i = -1;
```